# Error while running diskspd

Tags: testing, storage

I am running diskspd.exe tool which you can download from:

- [Diskspd Utility: A Robust Storage Testing Tool (superseding SQLIO)](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/DiskSpd-a-robust-storage-6cd2f223)
- https://github.com/Microsoft/diskspd

Operating system: Windows 2016 standard

I first get this:

```
D:\Diskspd\amd64fre>diskspd.exe -d15 -o4 -t4 -b8k -r -L -w50  testdiskspd.dat
Error opening file: testdiskspd.dat [2]
Error opening file: testdiskspd.dat [2]
Error opening file: testdiskspd.dat [2]
Error opening file: testdiskspd.dat [2]
```

After 15 seconds I get this:

```
There has been an error during threads execution

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

At the same time I get following pop up window:

[image]

I have write permission in folder `D:\Diskspd\amd64fre\`. I tested this by creating a .txt file.

This is what I can see in my windows log.

```
Faulting application name: diskspd.exe, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x54b9a313
Faulting module name: msvcrt.dll, version: 7.0.14393.0, time stamp: 0x57899b47
Exception code: 0x40000015
Fault offset: 0x000000000000c2c2
Faulting process id: 0x4b40
Faulting application start time: 0x01d3e2437778fe7f
Faulting application path: D:\Diskspd\amd64fre\diskspd.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll
Report Id: 2190f963-f533-4805-b23a-e3224c56e72d
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I needed to provide the file size switch and a value. Then it ran fine. From the document it was not clear that it was a mandatory parameter.

```
D:\Diskspd\amd64fre>diskspd.exe -d15 -o4 -t4 -b8k -r -L -w50  -c1G testdiskspd
```